# Where is the inspector window in Xcode 4.0.2

Tags: xcode, ios4

Before I used to open the inspector window ( Segmented Control Attributes) like: 
[image]

Now that I upgrated to Xcode 4.0.2 I have this:
[image]

How could I open the Inspector window in Xcode 4.0.2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem might be that you've hidden the Utilities view. To re-enable this, simply click on the rightmost of the "View" icons in the main window, as shown below.

[image: Utilities view toggle]

Incidentally, if you just single click on the .xib file, it'll open in the main view rather than a new window, which is probably more useful in this instance.

Comment: Agreed, you definitely don't want a new window because you lose access to the Utilities view. You *can*, however, add a new tab (and tear it off if you prefer): every tab gets its own utility view, editor splitting, etc.